# I can't subtract from jQuery .outerHeight() in if statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll

I am trying to create an ajax request when the div is scrolled to the bottom, and have come up with this code. When i'm not subtracting 100 from the elem.outerHeight() inside the if statement it all works fine, but i want to load the extra images before it hits the end, so i am trying to subtract 100, so it will load 100 pixels before the bottom, but it just won't work. Here is the code with the subtraction:

```
$('#thubnails').scroll(chk_scroll);

function chk_scroll(e) {
    var elem = $(e.currentTarget);

    if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() == elem.outerHeight()-100) {
        loadmoreimg();
        console.log(elem.outerHeight());
    }
}
```

Anyone have an answer?

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to catch exactly 100 px from bottom, but you could use greater or equal:

```
if (elem[0].scrollHeight - elem.scrollTop() >= elem.outerHeight() - 100) {
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: less or equal, or more or equal ?

Comment: That does not work, because as soon as i start scrolling it will start loading images, not what i am looking for, but neither <= works